# Метод destroy выполняется два раза

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Почему @post удаляется два раза?

При нажатии на удаление вылезает ошибка ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#destroy , сначало я думал что просто не происходит редиректа. Потом посмотрел в логах сервера, оказалось что Delete запрос выполняется два раза.

```
Started DELETE "/posts/60" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-15 22:54:31 +0300
Processing by PostsController#destroy as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Vz8s9TmUHOWSi6cZc0a/J96DNU/crL8LxvL1acjKJNg=", "id"=>"60"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3  LIMIT 1
Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "60"]]
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = 60
SQL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  [["id", 60]]
(175.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 179.9ms (ActiveRecord: 175.8ms)


Started DELETE "/posts/60" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-15 22:54:31 +0300
Processing by PostsController#destroy as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Vz8s9TmUHOWSi6cZc0a/J96DNU/crL8LxvL1acjKJNg=", "id"=>"60"}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Post Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "60"]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 1.2ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with id=60):
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:45:in `destroy'
```

posts_controller

```
def destroy
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @post.destroy
 redirect_to root_url
end
```

posts/show.html.erb

```
<% if can? :update, @post%>
    <%= link_to 'Редактировать', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<% end %>
<% if can? :delete, @post%>
    <%= link_to 'Удалить', @post, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Открой хромоконсоль, и посмотри, не отправляется ли AJAX-запрос на удаление перед обычным запросом.

Comment: С этого я начинал, firefox консоль так же показывает два POST запроса. AJAX'a нет.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, что виной прекомпиллированные ассеты на рабочей машине.

Comment: Да я уже нашел ответ на вопрос, так и есть. Из-за rake assets:precompile

Comment: @Coolguy оформите ответ, а то вопрос давно решён, а на сайте числится, как неотвеченный. Этот ответ, на мой взгляд, слабо раскрывает суть происходищего.

Answer (score 0):

Для деплоя на heroku сделал прекопиляцию rake assets:precompile, что создало в папке public/assets кучу .js файлов, после удаления которых собственно все заработало. Для локальной работы эти файлы не нужны.